# How to get attr with raw entities?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-entities, raw-data

I have data attr on my tag. Data attr has HTML entity in it. I can get content of that attr with `data` method from jQuery. However, HTML entity is modified and instead of getting `&mdash;` I get `—`.

How to get the raw content?

[JsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sTu2q/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is not possible.
As I understand it, the browser automatically resolves `&mdash;`, therefor you would have to encode it server-side to `&amp;mdash;`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sTu2q/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You could set the data attribute by jquery

```
$("span").data("foo", "&mdash;");
console.log($("span").data("foo"));
```

This produces `&mdash;` in the console